# Google Maps does not work with Android

Tags: android, maps, key

I have some problems getting Google Maps running on device/emulator.

The first problem appears as I want to get the key. I have produced my own fingerprint and entered it [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/maps-api-signup.html) to get the API key.

But then I get the error: "The fingerprint you entered is not valid."

Using other debug keys (I have found them online) I always got the Logcat error:

```
I/MapActivity(19787): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
E/MapActivity(19787): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

Answer (score 2):

Debug keys are "unique" for every workstation. You have to give to the signup site *your* debug key by executing:

```
keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Then you **place the new key that the signup site gives you** at the .xml file of your MapActivity.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="put_here_the_key_that_signup_site_gives_you"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it was another error.

I have Java 1.7 installed and for that keytool generates SHA1 fingerprints, but for a google maps key you need MD5 fingerprints.

So I changed Java 1.7 to Java 1.6, and then it works.

Comment: Added as answer in order other people with the same problem to be helped.